# How can you get Perl to stop when referencing an undef value?

Tags: perl, warnings, undef

How do you get Perl to stop and give a stack trace when you reference an undef value, rather than merely warning? It seems that `use strict;` isn't sufficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
use warnings FATAL => 'uninitialized';

use Carp ();
$SIG{__DIE__} = \&Carp::confess;
```

The first line makes the warning fatal.  The next two cause a stack trace when your program dies.

See also `man 3pm warnings` for more details.

Comment: As an alternative to the last two lines, `use Carp::Always`.

Answer (score 15):

Instead of the messy fiddling with `%SIG` proposed by everyone else, just `use Carp::Always` and be done.

Note that you can inject modules into a script without source modifications simply by running it with `perl -MCarp::Always`; furthermore, you can set the `PERL5OPT` environment variable to `-MCarp::Always` to have it loaded without even changing the invocation of the script. (See [`perldoc perlrun`](http://p3rl.org/run).)

Answer (score 4):

Include this:

```
use Carp ();
```

Then include *one* of these lines at the top of your source file:

```
local $SIG{__WARN__} = \&Carp::confess;
local $SIG{__WARN__} = \&Carp::cluck;
```

The `confess` line will give a stack trace, and the `cluck` line is much more terse.

Answer (score 2):

One way to make those warnings fatal is to install a signal handler for the **WARN** virtual-signal:

```
$SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die "Undef value: @_" if $_[0] =~ /undefined/ };
```

Answer (score 1):

Referencing an undef value wouldn't be a problem in itself, but it may cause warnings if your code is expecting it to be something other than undef. (particularly if you're trying to use that variable as an object reference).
You could put something in your code such as:

```
use Carp qw();

[....]

Carp::confess '$variableName is undef' unless defined $variableName;

[....]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this manually. The above "answers" do not work! Just test out this:

```
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'uninitialized';
use Carp ();
$SIG{__DIE__} = \&Carp::confess;

my $x = undef; # it would be enough to say my $x;
if (!$x->{test}) {
print "no warnings, no errors\n";
}
```

You will see that dereferencing did not cause any error messages or warnings. I know of no way of causing Perl to automatically detecting the use of undef as an invalid reference. I suspect this is so by design, so that autovivification works seamlessly.

Comment: an empty hash produces 0.  This appears to be a special case.

Comment: I think `if ($var)` is specially handled (for convenience) to treat `undef` as false. Maybe `if ("$var")` makes the difference.